# What are the hex ranges for Unicode categories?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, flex-lexer

I am building a parser in c for the Cooklang language. It is described here in EBNF:
https://github.com/cooklang/spec/blob/main/EBNF.md

I am building the parser using flex/bison. I need to take input in the form of UTF-8 instead of just ASCII. Thing is, I am only taking in some UTF-8 characters, all the general categories except for C and N, and some new line characters.
I also need to be able to tell which category the character is from so this is not just copying and pasting Unicode strings the same way one does with C strings.

I found this: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-flex/2005-01/msg00043.html as a good script for making hex ranges into lexer expressions to capture those hex ranges. But the issue I still have is figuring out which hex ranges to use for the different categories.

So, what hex ranges represent the different general categories of Unicode? If there is no single hex range that includes the entire category and only the code points in that category, where can I find a list of all the code points in it?

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Unicode general categories do not correspond to codepoint ranges. There are some large ranges with only one category (unassigned codes and ideograms spring to mind) but there are also hundreds, maybe thousands, of small ranges. The codepoint-to-general category assignments are in the Unicode Character Database; there is an instance of the UCD for each Unicode release and they are all freely available on the unicode.org site. Trying to build flex character classes in the way you are contemplating leads to enormous state machines, but it might be possible.

Comment: @rici is there any efficient way to accomplish this other than using thousands of little hex ranges?

Comment: Flex was not designed for multibyte encodings; for some simple applications, it can be made to work but it's really not ideal. You end up writing programs to generate lex patterns, which is not bad in itself; but it's tricky to make maintainable.

Comment: I've tried a few ways over the years, but there isn't anything which is really great. Depends how complicated your requirements are.

Comment: Are you trying to recognise Unicode identifier tokens according to the Unicode technical recommendations?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the last question. What I am trying to do is to take input that is in the form of UTF-8 and parse it. That means when there is a punctuation character, general category P, a different action is taken as compared to when a letter is found, general category L. I also need to be able to pass the data to a Bison file which then stores it in some form.

Comment: That's doesn't say much to me. What kind of parsing are you thinking of? It's actually pretty rare for a scanner to just say "this is a punctuation character", unless you are working on natural language parsing (in which case flex/bison isn't really the optimal toolset, I don't think.) In programming languages, *specific* punctuation characters have individual meaning, but the category is rarely, if ever, useful. Categories which are commonly used are identifier-start, identifier-continue, and identifier-end characters, which is why I asked if you were interested in tokenising identifiers.

Comment: It is a language parser, not a natural one though. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if Flex and Bison are the best tools for this particular problem.  First, your grammar does not easily fit a model in which the input can be unambiguously divided into tokens, and then those tokens parsed with a limited lookahead context-free grammar.

Perhaps you had in mind that flex would just categorise each incoming symbol and let the parser deal with assembling individual characters into grammatical structures. That can be done, although it's not a common approach. Usually, we would make a `word` a single token, for example. That will be difficult in this case, though, because there are contexts in which you want a word consisting only of digits to be considered to be a number, and other contexts in which it should be treated as a `word` (leaving aside for the moment the difficulty of handling `text`). That could possibly be accomplished, but it would require some tweaking of the grammar, and I'm not at all sure that all ambiguities could be resolved during a left-to-right parse.

It's certainly possible to use Flex only to categorise UTF-8 sequences into individual characters, segregated by general major category (perhaps with some minor refinements). I guess that's what your question is asking about, and the bad news is that Flex really isn't designed for UTF-8 processing, and furthermore Unicode was not designed with the goal of coalescing codepoint ranges. Unicode tries to place codepoints so that characters which come from the same script are all placed in a few aligned blocks of codepoints, leaving some codepoints unused in order to avoid mixing characters from some other script. Moreover, the unused codes are not always at the end of the blocks, because sometimes codepoints are assigned according to some algorithm --like capital letters are at a fixed offset from the equivalent lower-case letter-- which doesn't produce all codepoints (perhaps because sometimes the upper-to-lower case mapping isn't one-to-one.) You can see this at play in the two main blocks of [Greek characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_script_in_Unicode), with commonly used characters mostly assigned to the range [0x0370-0x03FF](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf), with accented and other less commonly-used characters in the code block [0x1F00-0x1FFF](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F00.pdf). Some other blocks are used for historical symbols, so you can spend quite a bit of time exploring that rabbit hole if you're interested enough.)

Once that pattern is repeated over and over again, you find that there are something like a thousand small runs of unassigned characters (category `Cn`) which interrupt the runs of other character categories. So you could collect all the possible UTF-8 sequences for each character category, but you would end up with a lot of ranges, possibly exceeding Flex's limits on the size of a pattern [See Notes 1 and 2].

Anyway, I think that idea is a dead-end, because you'll have immense problems writing a one-symbol lookahead grammar if the symbols are single characters. It's not even obvious to me how you might write a one-symbol lookahead grammar if you were to tokenise into words. Take, for example, the EBNF productions:

```
step     = { text item | ingredient | cookware | timer }-, new line character ;

ingredient           = one word ingredient | multiword ingredient ;
one word ingredient  = "@", ( word,          [ "{", { white space }, [ amount ], { white space }, "}" ] ) ;
multiword ingredient = "@", ( word, multiword, "{", { white space }, [ amount ], { white space }, "}" ) ;
```

The idea here, as I understand it, is that you can write

```
Mix the @Demerara sugar { 50 % grams} with the @butter and if desired @cinnamon
```

in which the ingredients are `Demarara sugar`, `butter` and `cinnamon`; it wasn't necessary to use brackets in the latter two cases because they are single-word ingredients; consequently, `and if desired` is a `text item`, like `Mix the`.

The problem here is that while the grammar is unambiguous (at least, in this little excerpt), the parser cannot tell that `and if desired` is not part of a multi-word ingredient until it sees the `@` which starts the next ingredient. Unfortunately, a one-symbol lookahead grammar has to decide whether or not to reduce `one word ingredient` long before the following `@` has been seen. And it can't reduce it prematurely, because there might be a `{` in the future, in which case there `one word ingredient` shouldn't be reduced at all.

Now, you could try to solve this problem by eliminating `one word ingredient` from the grammar, so that all the possibilities are reduced to ingredient, saving the parser from having to make an early decision. However, that will end up with the `text item` (if that is what it is) being included in the `ingredient` production, so you'll need a semantic action which fixes up the syntax tree in those cases. That's all possible but it's neither legible nor maintainable, and your ability to do it will basically be a function of how stubborn you are.

There were a few other things about that grammar that I noticed as I was puzzling through it, which I'll just mention here although they're not really relevant at all to your question. (And I probably missed lots of other details; these ones just sprung to my attention.)

First, if you write:

```
decimal = integer, ".", integer ;
```

after banning `integer`s which start with a `0`, then you have made it impossible to use decimals like `1.075`. `075` is not an integer, since it starts with a `0`. The fraction part of the decimal is an arbitrary sequence of `digit`s, which might or might not form an integer.

Second, I didn't get the rationale for

```
units    = multiword | punctuation character;
```

That seems to be saying that `heaping tablespoon` and `.` are both possibilities (but what's the point of `.`?), but that I cannot write `fld. oz.` (because the dots in the abbreviation aren't word characters). Maybe I misunderstood something.

I was going to add something about the pros and cons of banning particular characters in free text (in part because the character might be perfectly valid in a later Unicode version, which would create an interoperability problem for your various users) but I think I've written enough. I'd be happy to look at a more specific question accompanied by relevant details.

#### Notes

1. Flex handles macros --which for some reason are very popular in university classes-- by directly inserting the body of the macro in the referring pattern, with the result that you can't avoid the size limits by using macros.
2. Flex is almost 8-bit clean, though, so you don't actually have to use a four-byte escape code to represent a single byte value. Your text editor might not be so helpful, though.

Comment: Ok so about the question: Is there anywhere I can find these little runs bundled together in a nice format, rather than having to sift through every block on the Unicode website? Is there anyone that has done this before that you or anyone else knows of?

Comment: @Seth: lots of people have done it :-( but most people who use the data use it in a more convenient api, such as ICU. Anyway, it's easy to extract from the UCD. The file `UnicodeData` contains basic information for every assigned character. It's essentially one row per character, except for a half-dozen ranges where characters don't have individual names.

Comment: @SethHarlaar: if you're comfortable with Python, the important parts of the UCD are available in the `unicodedata` module. It's easier to use than parsing the text files, although the text files are designed to be easy to parse.